# Cannot deserialize JIRA IssueField with Jackson coming from webhook event

Tags: json, jackson, jira, json-deserialization

I created a JIRA bug and sent the subsequent generated event to a SpringBoot a via webhook. That works so far. In the SpringBoot app I tried to deserialize the received JSON. To achieve this I have an IssueEvent class which has an Issue field:

```
package my.package.domain.jira.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.ChangelogGroup;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User;

/**
 * RootObject JSON
 *
 */
public class IssueEvent implements Serializable {
 /**
 * 
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 4467263405878138432L;

 private Long timestamp;
 private String webhookEvent;
 @JsonProperty("issue_event_type_name")
 private String issueEventTypeName;
 private User user;
 private Issue issue;
 private ChangelogGroup changelog;
...
}
```

Here's the JSON generated by JIRA when creating a bug/issue:

```
{
"timestamp": 1516692474575,
"webhookEvent": "jira:issue_created",
"issue_event_type_name": "issue_created",
"user": {
    "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/user?username=bla",
    "name": "bla",
    "key": "abla",
    "emailAddress": "a.b@xyz.com",
    "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10336",
        "24x24": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10336",
        "16x16": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10336",
        "32x32": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10336"
    },
    "displayName": "bla",
    "active": true,
    "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
},
"issue": {
    "id": "10623",
    "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issue/10623",
    "key": "COVA-90",
    "fields": {
        "issuetype": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issuetype/10004",
            "id": "10004",
            "description": "Ein Problem, das die Funktionen des Produkts beeinträchtigt oder verhindert.",
            "iconUrl": "http://localhost:9090/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10303&avatarType=issuetype",
            "name": "Bug",
            "subtask": false,
            "avatarId": 10303
        },
        "components": [],
        "timespent": null,
        "timeoriginalestimate": null,
        "description": "dhmedhmed",
        "project": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/project/10000",
            "id": "10000",
            "key": "COVA",
            "name": "CoVA",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "http://localhost:9090/secure/projectavatar?avatarId=10324",
                "24x24": "http://localhost:9090/secure/projectavatar?size=small&avatarId=10324",
                "16x16": "http://localhost:9090/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10324",
                "32x32": "http://localhost:9090/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&avatarId=10324"
            }
        },
        "fixVersions": [
            {
                "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/version/10000",
                "id": "10000",
                "name": "Version 1.0",
                "archived": false,
                "released": true,
                "releaseDate": "2017-11-29"
            }
        ],
        "aggregatetimespent": null,
        "resolution": null,
        "timetracking": {},
        "customfield_10005": "0|i000gf:",
        "attachment": [],
        "aggregatetimeestimate": null,
        "resolutiondate": null,
        "workratio": -1,
        "summary": "jrzj",
        "lastViewed": null,
        "watches": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issue/COVA-90/watchers",
            "watchCount": 0,
            "isWatching": false
        },
        "creator": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/user?username=bla",
            "name": "bla",
            "key": "abla",
            "emailAddress": "a.b@xyz.com",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10336",
                "24x24": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10336",
                "16x16": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10336",
                "32x32": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10336"
            },
            "displayName": "bla",
            "active": true,
            "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "subtasks": [],
        "created": "2018-01-23T08:27:54.388+0100",
        "reporter": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/user?username=bla",
            "name": "bla",
            "key": "abla",
            "emailAddress": "a.b@xyz.com",
            "avatarUrls": {
                "48x48": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10336",
                "24x24": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10336",
                "16x16": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10336",
                "32x32": "http://localhost:9090/secure/useravatar?size=medium&avatarId=10336"
            },
            "displayName": "bla",
            "active": true,
            "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "customfield_10000": null,
        "aggregateprogress": {
            "progress": 0,
            "total": 0
        },
        "priority": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/priority/3",
            "iconUrl": "http://localhost:9090/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
            "name": "Medium",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "labels": [
            "Test",
            "Bug"
        ],
        "customfield_10004": [
            "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@14d495fe[id=1,rapidViewId=1,state=ACTIVE,name=Sample Sprint 2,startDate=2017-11-30T02:29:06.805+01:00,endDate=2017-12-14T02:49:06.805+01:00,completeDate=<null>,sequence=1,goal=<null>]"
        ],
        "environment": "dghndghmnedghmn",
        "timeestimate": null,
        "aggregatetimeoriginalestimate": null,
        "versions": [
            {
                "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/version/10000",
                "id": "10000",
                "name": "Version 1.0",
                "archived": false,
                "released": true,
                "releaseDate": "2017-11-29"
            }
        ],
        "duedate": null,
        "progress": {
            "progress": 0,
            "total": 0
        },
        "comment": {
            "comments": [],
            "maxResults": 0,
            "total": 0,
            "startAt": 0
        },
        "issuelinks": [
            {
                "id": "10421",
                "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issueLink/10421",
                "type": {
                    "id": "10000",
                    "name": "Blocks",
                    "inward": "is blocked by",
                    "outward": "blocks",
                    "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10000"
                },
                "outwardIssue": {
                    "id": "10616",
                    "key": "COVA-83",
                    "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issue/10616",
                    "fields": {
                        "summary": "fj,t.uoöpuz.ötultl",
                        "status": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/status/10000",
                            "description": "",
                            "iconUrl": "http://localhost:9090/",
                            "name": "Aufgaben",
                            "id": "10000",
                            "statusCategory": {
                                "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
                                "id": 2,
                                "key": "new",
                                "colorName": "blue-gray",
                                "name": "Aufgaben"
                            }
                        },
                        "priority": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/priority/3",
                            "iconUrl": "http://localhost:9090/images/icons/priorities/medium.svg",
                            "name": "Medium",
                            "id": "3"
                        },
                        "issuetype": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issuetype/10004",
                            "id": "10004",
                            "description": "Ein Problem, das die Funktionen des Produkts beeinträchtigt oder verhindert.",
                            "iconUrl": "http://localhost:9090/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10303&avatarType=issuetype",
                            "name": "Bug",
                            "subtask": false,
                            "avatarId": 10303
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "votes": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/issue/COVA-90/votes",
            "votes": 0,
            "hasVoted": false
        },
        "worklog": {
            "startAt": 0,
            "maxResults": 20,
            "total": 0,
            "worklogs": []
        },
        "assignee": null,
        "updated": "2018-01-23T08:27:54.388+0100",
        "status": {
            "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/status/10000",
            "description": "",
            "iconUrl": "http://localhost:9090/",
            "name": "Aufgaben",
            "id": "10000",
            "statusCategory": {
                "self": "http://localhost:9090/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
                "id": 2,
                "key": "new",
                "colorName": "blue-gray",
                "name": "Aufgaben"
            }
        }
    }
},
"changelog": {
    "id": "10742",
    "items": [
        {
            "field": "Link",
            "fieldtype": "jira",
            "from": null,
            "fromString": null,
            "to": "COVA-83",
            "toString": "This issue blocks COVA-83"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Since the JIRA classes don't have a prameterless default constructors I tried to use *Mixins*. It works well for the User class but seems not for Issue class:

```
package my.package.domain.jira.util;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Attachment;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicComponent;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicPriority;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicProject;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicVotes;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicWatchers;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.ChangelogGroup;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Comment;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.IssueField;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.IssueLink;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.IssueType;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Operations;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Resolution;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Status;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Subtask;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.TimeTracking;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Version;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Worklog;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

/**
 *
 */
public abstract class IssueMixin {
 @JsonCreator
 public IssueMixin(@JsonProperty("summary") String summary, @JsonProperty("self") URI self, @JsonProperty("key") String key, 
 @JsonProperty("id") Long id, @JsonProperty("project") BasicProject project, @JsonProperty("issueType") IssueType issueType, 
 @JsonProperty("status") Status status, @JsonProperty("description") String description, @JsonProperty("priority") BasicPriority priority, 
 @JsonProperty("resolution") Resolution resolution, @JsonProperty("attachments") Collection<Attachment> attachments, @JsonProperty("reporter") User reporter, 
 @JsonProperty("assignee") User assignee, @JsonProperty("creationDate") DateTime creationDate, @JsonProperty("updateDate") DateTime updateDate, 
 @JsonProperty("dueDate") DateTime dueDate, @JsonProperty("affectedVersion") Collection<Version> affectedVersion, 
 @JsonProperty("fixVersions") Collection<Version> fixVersions, @JsonProperty("components") Collection<BasicComponent> components, 
 @JsonProperty("timeTracking") TimeTracking timeTracking, @JsonProperty("fields") Collection<IssueField> issueFields, 
 @JsonProperty("comments") Collection<Comment> comments, @JsonProperty("transitionsUri") URI transitionsUri, 
 @JsonProperty("issueLinks") Collection<IssueLink> issueLinks, @JsonProperty("votes") BasicVotes votes, @JsonProperty("worklogs") Collection<Worklog> worklogs, 
 @JsonProperty("watchers") BasicWatchers watchers, @JsonProperty("expandos") Iterable<String> expandos, @JsonProperty("subtasks") Collection<Subtask> subtasks, 
 @JsonProperty("changelog") Collection<ChangelogGroup> changelog, @JsonProperty("operations") Operations operations, @JsonProperty("labels") Set labels ) {}
}
```

This Mixin matches exactly the constructor of class Issue from package com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.

I get the following Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: 
 {...JSON from above...}; line: 1, column: 709] (through reference chain: my.package.domain.jira.entity.IssueEvent["issue"]->com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue["fields"])
```

It seems as if the JSON generated from JIRA does not match its own class Issue.

The JSON around the Issue class contains further code (which may be of class com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent). First I tried to code this POJO on my own but I would prefer to use the JIRA domain classes...but how can I reference this class. Trynig to use the jira-api dependency fails that jta 1.0.1  dependency is missing.

How can I solve this problem?

Okay. I found out that I have to exclude the JTA dependency internally used by jira-api dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jira.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>jta</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Still I don't know how to decode/deserialize the JSON to the JIRA domain objects...